# How to change the Title label text alignment of the section when it was present

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift3

I'm loading the `UITableView` with two section and I've used `viewForHeaderInSection` method to set the title for each section. Initially I've set the `title label` text alignment as `.left`. Now when I scroll the table view and the second section was present i want to change the `title label` text alignment to `.center`. And when I scroll down the table view i want to show as initial(like second section text alignment as `.left`). How can I Do that?

Here is the `TableView Delegate`method I've used to load the section.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

            let headerLabel:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: 20))

    headerLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    headerLabel.textAlignment = .left
    headerLabel.font = Fonts.kFontWith_14

        if section == 0
        {
            headerLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("Suggested", comment: "")
            headerLabel.backgroundColor = Colors.kAppBgColor
            headerLabel.textAlignment = .left
        }
        else{
            headerLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("Contacts", comment: "")
            headerLabel.backgroundColor = Colors.kLightBlueColor
            headerLabel.textAlignment = .left

        }
    headerLabel.sizeToFit()
    return headerLabel

}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. For section 0 center alignment and rest of the sections left alignment?? And remove `headerLabel.sizeToFit()` otherwise alignment won't work

Comment: What i want is initially when table is loaded i want to show the all section headers titles on left side. When i scroll the table view and the presented section title as center. I hope you understand.@Bilal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take one `bool` variable on global, The follwoing delegate will respond you when scroll happens

```
var isDirection = Bool()

func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    if velocity.y > 0 {
        print("up")
        isDirection = true
    }
    if velocity.y < 0 {
        print("down")
       isDirection = false
    }
}

Then write a condition in respective `tableview` delegate

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

            let headerLabel:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: 20))

    headerLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    headerLabel.textAlignment = .left
    headerLabel.font = Fonts.kFontWith_14

        if section == 0
        {
            headerLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("Suggested", comment: "")
            headerLabel.backgroundColor = Colors.kAppBgColor
        }
        else{
            headerLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("Contacts", comment: "")
            headerLabel.backgroundColor = Colors.kLightBlueColor

        }
      if isDirection{
                   headerLabel.textAlignment = .left
       }else{
                   headerLabel.textAlignment = .center
       }


    return headerLabel

}
```

Remove

```
headerLabel.sizeToFit()
```

This is sample, you enable `bool` variable based on your scroll direction. If delegate does not call, reload your table on  `scrollViewWillEndDragging`

Comment: Ok. I will try this.

Comment: Your Solution is worked for me partially. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way for my problem
Take a bool value and a `CGPoint` globally and assign the `UITableView.ContentOffset` value to the `defaultOffset` in `viewDidload` Method.

```
var isScroll:Bool = Bool()
var defaultOffSet = CGPoint()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
defaultOffSet = tableView.contentOffset
}
```

And I've used this `scrollView` delegate method

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if  contactsTableView.rectForHeader(inSection: 1).origin.y > contactsTableView.contentOffset.y-defaultOffSet.y {
        isScrolled = false
    }
    else if tableView.rectForHeader(inSection: 0).origin.y <= tableView.contentOffset.y-defaultOffSet.y{
        isScrolled = true
    }
        tableView.reloadData()
  }
```

And In my tableview `viewForHeaderInSection`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

     let headerLabel:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: 20))

    headerLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    headerLabel.textAlignment = .left
    headerLabel.font = Fonts.kFontWith_14

        if section == 0
        {
            headerLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("Suggested", comment: "")
            headerLabel.backgroundColor = Colors.kAppBgColor
            headerLabel.textAlignment = .left
        }
        else{
            headerLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("Contacts", comment: "")
            headerLabel.backgroundColor = Colors.kLightBlueColor

            if isScrolled{
            headerLabel.textAlignment = .center
            headerLabel.backgroundColor = Colors.kAppBgColor

            }
        }
    }

}
```